# Second Partial Derivative of the function

Tags: derivatives

$$f(x,y) = \tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$
How do you calculate the $$f_{xy}$$ and $$f_{yy}$$

I tried do it but my answer was wrong.

Comment: What do you obtain for $f_x$ and $f_y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_y = \frac 1{1-\frac {y^2}{x^2}} \frac 1x  = \frac {x}{x^2-y^2}\\
f_x = \frac 1{1-\frac {y^2}{x^2}} (-\frac {y}{x^2})  = \frac {y}{y^2-x^2}$

$f_{yy} = \frac {2xy}{(x^2-y^2)^2}$

$f_{yx} = \frac {(x^2-y^2) - x(2x)}{(x^2+y^2)^2} = \frac {-(x^2 +y^2)}{(x^2-y^2)^2}$

Answer (score 1):

Well do you know how to obtain the derivative of $y=\arctan(x)$?

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
y&= \tanh^{-1}(x), \\
x&=\tanh(y), \\ 
dx &= \text{sech}^2(y) \; dy \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{1}{\text{sech}^2(y)}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Now use both facts that $\text{sech}^2(y) = 1 - \tanh^2(y)$ and $\tanh^2(y)=x^2$ by our definition above. Hence
\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{1-x^2}.
\end{equation}

So, your problem is given by$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x \partial y}$.
You just need to apply what I have done above and then take another derivative of a fraction. Hope this helps.

Comment: Note this is arctanh y/x and not arctan y/x